# what could be the reason that a file is reachable locally but not in docker?

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to deploy a flask app in docker, the default-config.yaml file can be reached when i was doing a local python server.py, but was rendered as not existing in a docker environment

The structure of the folder is

```
foo
├── __init__.py
├── config
│   └── default-config.yaml    
└── web
    ├── __init__.py
    │   
    └── server.py
```

- when running locally, it is successfully compiled
- when using `docker run image`, it gives error `The file '<--MYPATH-->' does not exist`

`__main__.ConfigFileDoesNotExistException: The file '../config/default-config.yaml' does not exist`

- when building the image, `ls '<--MYPATH-->'` shows the file is there.

`Step 4/9 : RUN ls ./foo/config
     ---> Running in 1e3096b9ccf0
    default-config.yaml`

P.S. I've used 
ADD . /code and 
WORKDIR /code

Very confused why the file is interpreted as not existing. Any hints?

Thanks

the docker file is below

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN ls ./foo/config

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev

RUN pip install psycopg2

RUN python3 setup.py install
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 

CMD ["python3", "./foo/web/server.py"]
```

Comment: Please add your Dockerfile that we can see how you're building the image

Comment: You should never access files from Python web applications via relative paths, or rely on the current working directory being a specific directory, as the current working directory could be anything depending on server and environment, and could change. Always calculate the absolute path in some way, such as ``file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'filename.txt')``. See: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory

Comment: didn't know this solution before. no wonder it kept causing trouble. thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me if there's some flask-specific directory magic going on, but I'm thinking that it's a matter of where the python interpreter is being run from.

I'm guessing that you ran `python server.py` from the `web` directory when testing it locally. If you were to try running `python foo/web/server.py` from the directory containing `Dockerfile`, then you would get the same error you posted above.

So in the Dockerfile, try setting the `WORKDIR` to the web directory.
Of course, the `RUN`, `CMD` and `ls` lines will also change.

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code/foo/web
RUN ls ../config

RUN apk update && \
    apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python-dev musl-dev && \
    apk add postgresql-dev

RUN pip install psycopg2

RUN python3 ../../setup.py install
RUN pip install -r ../../requirements.txt 

CMD ["python3", "server.py"]
```

**EDIT:**

Alternatively, just use a second `WORKDIR` command directly before the `CMD` line, so everything would remain the same as the Dockerfile you posted, except the last two lines are

```
WORKDIR /code/foo/web
CMD ["python3", "server.py"]
```

Good luck!

Oliver